# Do the following functions exist?

Tags: general-topology

While practicing for my topology exam, I stumbled upon the following question from a previous exam:

Give a proof of your answer:

(a) Is there a continuous surjective map from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C} - \{0 \} $?

(b) Is there a continuous surjective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R} - \{0 \} $?

(c) Is there a continuous surjective map from $\mathbb{R} - \{ 0 \}$ to $\mathbb{R} $?

(d) Is there a continuous surjective map from $\mathbb{S^1}$ to $\mathbb{S^1} - \{1 \} $?

I think the answer to (a) and (b) is "Yes, there is. Those are the identitiy functions $id_{\mathbb{C} }$ and $id_{\mathbb{R} }$". Is this true? And what about (c) and (d)? And how do you prove it?

Edit: I now know that my proposed functions are no good (they aren't even functions!). So I guess the questions remain: do the continuous surjective maps exist?

Comment: Note that any constant function is continuous, and so each of these _as presently stated_ is true.  However I suspect that there might be some additional requirements on the desired functions (perhaps surjectivity?).  (Also, for your proposed answers to (a) and (b): what is $\mathrm{id} (0)$, and how is it an element of the desired range?)

Comment: whoops, sorry. Indeed: surjectivity is an additional requirement.

Comment: @ArthurFischer $id(0)$ for (a) and (b) is equal to $0+0i$ and just $0$ respectively, I guess. But I thought it doesn't matter it isn't an element of the desired range. I thought surjectivity only requires that for a map $f: D \to B$ it's true that $f[D] = B$.

Comment: True about the definition of surjectivity… but the problem with "the identity function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$" is that such an object fails to be a function.

Comment: @EricStucky Why does it fail to be a function?

Comment: $f : X \to Y$ means that every element of $X$ is associated (by $f$) with an element of $Y$.  So the identity mapping on, for example, $\mathbb{R}$ cannot have range $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, since $\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}} ( 0 ) = 0 \notin \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: @ArthurFischer aha! Glad to finally learn such a thing after studying mathematics for two years...

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain his/her reason as to why s/he downvoted. I know this isn't a very bright/insightful question, but it's an honest one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For (a) and (c), we can do it, with (for example) the maps $z\mapsto e^z$ and $x\mapsto x-\frac1x.$ For (b), it is impossible, since the continuous image of any real-valued function on $\Bbb R$ is a singleton, interval, ray, or all of $\Bbb R$--more generally, continuous images of (non-empty) connected sets are again (non-empty) connected. For (d) it is impossible, since a continuous image of a compact set is compact, but $\Bbb S^1-\{1\}$ is *not* compact.

Comment: I was a bit skeptical about your claim for (b), but now I see that you're using the fact that these are the only connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Might be worth an edit to mention this.

Comment: @Eric: Good point. Done!

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. I have one question though. For (c), you chose $x \mapsto x - \frac{1}{x} $. Can we also pick $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x} $ ?

Comment: @Max: What is the range of that map? Is it all of $\Bbb R$? If it isn't, then we can't use it.

Comment: @CameronBuie ehm I am not entirely sure what the range is... I thought it is all of $\mathbb{R}$, but I guess it isn't. I guess the range isn't all of $\mathbb{R}$ because it doesn't reach $0$, right? And your function does reach zero because we can pick $x = 1$.

Comment: @Max: Bingo! In fact your range hits everything *but* $0$. As for my function, it does indeed reach $0$, but it takes more than that to prove surjectivity. I'd consider showing that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(x-\frac1x\right)=-\infty$ and that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(x-\frac1x\right)=+\infty,$ and using intermediate value theorem.